# Quantity increment decrements not working for grouped product magento 2

Tags: magento2, grouped-products, quantity, qty-increment, decrements

*As a test I created 3 simple products and associated them with a grouped product.*

*I enabled qty increments for the grouped product and set the allowed increment.*

*The system allows you to add product quantities to the cart that do not meet the increment rule.*

*I also tested this with a configurable product (using the same 3 simples) and in this case it worked as expected.*

*Does anyone know if this is a known issue? Or if there are any work arounds for it?*

*IS there any configuration need to be done for his through admin panel?*

Answer (score 0):

could you please share me your code 
i also implemented code for quantity increment and decrement for grouped products but in my case all are working fine but when i click on increment or decrement it is applying to all products in that group
please find my code here
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1aY-ANcC1pL0j1P33ANZFGwXnXMoldkaO